# formula to determine designation point given a variable

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i have a game inwhich a bait is thrown determined by a variable of a power meter, when the meter is full it returns a variable of 1 when half 0.5 and when low near 0, how can i use this to determine how far my "bait will be thrown" onto the screen?
i have tried how ever the X value would not be consistent with my fishing rod placement, and when the point is decided i will have to move my bait to that point and stop.

> _destinationY = Math.abs(_maxY - (_maxY * power));
>
> _destinationX = Math.abs(_maxX - (_maxX * power));

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author ...
     */
    public class Bullet extends MovieClip
    {
        //variables
        private var _stageRef:Stage;
        private var _maxX:Number = 1024;
        private var _maxY:Number = 768;
        private var _destinationY:Number;
        private var _destinationX:Number;
        private var _speedVector:Point = new Point();
        private var _moveFactor:Number = 0.9;
        public var  hit:MovieClip;
        private var _fishes:Vector.<HFish> = new Vector.<HFish>;
        private var _bulletLengthVector:Point = new Point();
        private var awpSnd:awpSound
        private var _power:Number = 1;
        
        public function Bullet(stageRef:Stage,x:Number,y:Number,targetPoint:Point,power:Number) 
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            _stageRef = stageRef;
            _maxX = _stageRef.stageWidth;
            _maxY = _stageRef.stageHeight;
            
            //movement
            _destinationY = Math.abs(_maxY - (_maxY * power));
            _destinationX = Math.abs(_maxX - (_maxX * power));
            trace ("landing at Y " + _destinationY);
            trace ("landing at X " + _destinationX);
            if (_destinationY > _maxY)
                _destinationY = _maxY;
            if (_destinationX > _maxX)
                _destinationX = _maxX;
            
            
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);
            //determine bullet moving speed
            
        }
    
        private function loop(e:Event) : void
        {
            
            //move bullet
            this.x += _speedVector.x;
            this.y += _speedVector.y;
            //remove bullet bound check
            if (this.x > _maxX || this.x < 0)
                removeSelf();
                else if (this.y > _maxY || this.y < 0)
                removeSelf();
        
        }
        
        private function removeSelf() : void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
         
            if (stage.contains(this))
                stage.removeChild(this);
        }
    
        
    }

}
```

a screenshot of the game.
[image]

Comment: in the picture shown, the bait should be thrown to the centre of the screen because the power is half, and the rod position is at centre

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why you're using such a complex forumla for this. If you simply want the person to be able to reach a maxX and maxY number, then multiply maxX and maxY by the total power, since the power range is from 0-1. This way if your power level is .7, then the throw will be 70 percent of the max distance. Easy, unless I'm missing something else.

**Update**

Regarding finding the angle between your fishing rod and where the bait landed, just use this helper class I found on google to get the angle between the bait point and your rod point:

http://www.untoldentertainment.com/blog/2008/12/08/as3-helper-class-findangle/

So basically just cast a new Point object, set the X/Y to the X/Y of your bait, then cast a secont Point object, set the X/Y to the X/Y of your rod and then pass them to this helper class. The class will find the angle in RADIANS. Ensure that you convert them to degrees since the flash player uses degrees for display object rotation. You can do this also inside the helper class or by hand: 
`var degrees:Number = radians * 180 / Math.PI;`

Comment: hi, yes i did that but if i were to use the power level to gauge my X thrown, for example 0.5 * my stage max width and gives 500, my fishing rod can be rotated 170degrees and when the bait is "thrown" to the point, my fishing rod is not facing the bait

Comment: Ohhhhhh I see so this is an issue of getting the angle between your fishing rod and the final destination of the bait, correct?

Comment: yes.currently my fishing rod is rotatable my MouseEvent_MOVE. and when i "fire" the bait. if based on this formula my gauge times my _maxX there would be a "jump" from my current rotation to face the bait thrown position

Comment: Okay so now I'm confused again. So the issue isn't getting the angle, it's about preventing this "jump" and tweening the rotation into place or what?

Comment: hi, please take alook at the uploaded swf http://megaswf.com/serve/1156989 . you can hold your mouse at the hand drag up or down to move the power meter and release to "thrown the bait" im having trouble calculating the moving of the "bait" from the tip of the rod to a designated X and Y determined by the power gauge value of 0-1

Comment: hi, i think i may have confused you, what i meant to do is to have my bait be thrown out of the tip of the fishing rod in the direction of the fishing rod.